# Call by reference: Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, opencv, pass-by-reference

I try to return multiple values by reference.

```
enum Color {ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, RED};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CvScalar hsv_min, hsv_max;
    choose_color(RED, hsv_min, hsv_max);

    return 0;
}

void choose_color(Color farbe, CvScalar &min, CvScalar &max) {
    switch (farbe) {
        case ORANGE:
            min = cvScalar(0,50,50);
            max = cvScalar(0,255,255);
            break;
        default:
            throw "choose color: invalid case!";
            break;
    }
 };
```

Why do I get "use of undeclared identifier" for the choose_color call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `main` function needs to know that your `choose_color` exists.

You need to do a forward declaration (place the [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) of the function before the `main` function):

```
enum Color {ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, VIOLET, RED};

// Forward declaration
void choose_color(Color farbe, CvScalar &min, CvScalar &max); // function prototype

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CvScalar hsv_min, hsv_max;
    choose_color(RED, hsv_min, hsv_max);

    return 0;
}

void choose_color(Color farbe, CvScalar &min, CvScalar &max) {
// ...
};
```

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) is great explanation about forward declaration.

The other solution is to define the `main` after your `choose_color` function.

Comment: I'd note that this is often referred to as "prototyping" the function.

Comment: @BrainSteel I edited my post to talk about prototype. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud You need to move the forward-declaration of `choose_color` *after* the definition of `Color`.

Comment: @DanielFrey Outch ... That's true... I fixed it. Thank you for pointing this out !

Comment: In general what is preferred? Forward declaration or definition of main after all functions?

Answer (score 0):

place main() *after* choose_color() or, better, declare the function above main():

```
void choose_color(Color farbe, CvScalar &min, CvScalar &max);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
...
}
```